# How to set function/script/method only for specific browser?

Tags: jquery, browser

How to set function/method/event etc only for specific browser.
For example i want to do this only if browser is Chrome

```
$('#table').width($('#table_body td:eq(0) tr').length * WH);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function from [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8S2E/)

```
function BrowserDetection() {

    //Check if browser is IE or not
    if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is InternetExplorer");
    }
    //Check if browser is Chrome or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is Chrome");
    }
    //Check if browser is Firefox or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is FireFox");
    }
    //Check if browser is Safari or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
        alert("Browser is Safari");
    }
    //Check if browser is Opera or not
    else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {
        alert("Browser is Opera");
    }
}
BrowserDetection();
```

So for your case, you would have:

```
//Check if browser is Chrome or not
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
    $('#table').width($('#table_body td:eq(0) tr').length * WH);
}
```

Thanks to the Microsoft forum for the example - http://forums.asp.net/t/1965754.aspx?Determine+the+browser+using+Javascript+JQuery